# Redirect to web site with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter, how  to redirect user to gmail.com after hitting on a link ? I'm really stuck to do that because the link is out of my site. 
Something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>http/www.gmail.com"><?php echo $billet->Courriel;?></a>
```

Comment: just write <a href="www.gmail.com">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple use like below

```
<a href="http://www.gmail.com" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
```

add http:// before URL